# APi parse 2 digits after the decimal point?

Tags: php

I have a code that updates the list of items from the Steam service game by API. In response, these prices come to me looks like: `"price":0.64000000000000001,"count":897,"bprice":0.080000000000000002`. How can I do  at the API parsing stage so that the value `price` and `bprice` had 2 digits after the decimal point?

My parse code:

```
public static function updatePrices()
{
    if ($data = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::STEAMP)) ?? false) {
        if ($data->success) {

            $items_in_res = new \stdClass();
            foreach($data->items as $key => $item) {
                if ($item->count > 50  ) {
                    if ($item->bcount > 20) {
                        if ($item->price <= 1) {
                            $item->price = 0.64;
                        }
                        $items_in_res->$key = $item;
                    }
                }
            }

            Storage::disk('local')->put(self::Prices, json_encode([
                'time' => time(),
                'items' => $items_in_res
            ]));

            return $items_in_res;
        } else {
            \Log::error('Error: ' . $data->message);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        \Log::error('Error updating prices!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for this.

```
echo number_format($item->price,2);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/NnZlb

Just a side note that `number_format` also [`rounds silently`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#88424).

Comment: @ahab4ik Did you see the demo? It works perfectly fine. Can you share the code of how you tried by adding it in your post?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$item->price= sprintf("%.2f", $item->price);
```

The underlying problem is that the original number cannot be represented as an exact floating point number on the system it was generated on. It was probably a floating point number that was converted to a string as part of JSON encoding.

A number of functions in languages handle this for you by doing silently rounding the insignificant digits to zero. Whatever produced the original JSON did not.

Since you don't need the value as a number you can use the sprintf() function to convert it to a 2 decimal point string representation of the number.

Comment: If you can use it as a string I've modified the answer.

Comment: "try this _code_" answers really need to include an explanation of what it is and doing. (I did not downvote)

Comment: @IncredibleHat you're absolutely right. I was doing a drive-by solution to solve the problem. Should have put it in a comment in that case or added the explanation. I have modified my answer to more fully explain the issue.